# Python query to Redshift PostgreSQL Database

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I have been stuck on getting a Pandas dataframe to Redshift.

Libraries via Anaconda:
Python - 3.7.9
SQL Alchemy - 1.3.2
Pandas - 1.1.3
Psycopg2 - 2.8.6

Code:

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

conn = create_engine('postgresql://UserName:Password@Database')
df.to_sql('table_name', con=conn, schema='schema_name', index=False, if_exists='append')
```

From df.info:

| # | Column | Non-Null Count | Dtype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | close_date | 34506 non-null | object |
| 1 | NumberVar1 | 34506 non-null | float64 |
| 2 | Total | 34506 non-null | float64 |
| 3 | NumberVar2 | 34506 non-null | float64 |
| 4 | Building | 34506 non-null | object |
| 5 | NumberVar3 | 34506 non-null | float64 |
| 6 | Year | 34506 non-null | int64 |
| 7 | month | 34506 non-null | int64 |
| 8 | wk_number | 34506 non-null | object |
| 9 | DateStamp | 34506 non-null | object |

The issue:
I know the connection is working - when I run this I can create tables in the schema using the column headings. This is where it hangs, no data will be input into this table in the cluster even after an hour of running. I have tried using chunksize=5 and method='multi' variables in the to_sql arguments and neither bore fruit.